# Is it possible to install server software while I just have a hosting

Tags: server, backend, hosting

I'm new to web back-end and about to deploy a website(with both backend and frontend). As far as I know, **If you own a server, you can install whatever software you want**. But how about when you have a free hosting, **is it possible for you to install softwares like Tomcat, Mysql,etc yourself.**

Ps: as far as I know, hosting is a folder inside a server, so in my opinion, you'll depend on the server which contains the hosting. Still I get confused.
I highly appreciate you all for spending time read this post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hosting is just deploying your applications and then serve them to the internet. If you are using free hosting, I suppose that they must be managed service which mean you cannot do anything except the functions the hosting provider provide. In my opinion, it is better to get your own vps if you want to control your server fully. You can just install software you want in ubuntu or other supported os, and then serve your port to public. If you would like to try, you can use some cheap vps provider first like Contabo VPS.